# 6 separate UIViewControllers or just one with different data sources decided at segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm building an iOS app in Swift which has a start page with 6 buttons. Each of those buttons will segue to a table view controller whose data is managed with an `NSFetchedResultsController` (application uses core data). Now, I can see it being easy to create 6 `UITableViewControllers` however I'm wondering if it would be more sensible to send each button to the same `UITableViewController` and just change the data loaded/managed by setting some kind of flag in the `prepareForSegue` method?

What's the best practice here? It seems crazy to have 6 `tableViewController`s each backed by it's own `NSFetchedResultsController` when big portions of the required code for each are reusable and could be subclassed out and used multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can code a single view controller in a way that supports all six with a single code base, reusing a single `UITableViewController` makes perfect sense. Other approaches include

- **Composition** - make a class for the data source, configure it before opening the table view, and pass it to the table view on segue
- **Subclassing** - make an abstract base view controller, and extend it six times. Override an abstract method or two to reduce the amount of repetition
- **Helper** - make a class that holds all reusable logic shared across the six view controllers, and call its methods from six very slip controllers.

One thing you want to *avoid* is code like this:

```
if (viewControllerType == ViewControllerOne) {
     doSomethingSpecial()
} else if (viewControllerType == ViewControllerTwo) {
     doSomethingElseSpecial()
} ... // and so on
```

When you have a chain like this, you know that you've missed an opportunity to subcllass.

Comment: Nice suggestions - composition was what I had in mind, didn't know it had a name, better fits MVC than bunging it all in the tableviewcontroller as well

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this question will be closed as opinion-based, but here's my thoughts:

Definitely use only one view controller and changed the data source in `prepareforsegue()`

Imagine having 6 different controllers and then deciding in 6 months that you want to change the entire UI!!! I did that. Wasn't pretty. And that was the point when I reconfigured everything and scaled down my total number of view controllers.

And don't even get me started on the pains of having to do auto layout on multiple screens. You see where I'm going with this.

Comment: Part of my thinking was to avoid that scenario of 6 UI mods in future, Apple makes it so easy to just throw in new Controllers where they act as delegates and data sources it's difficult to break out of that pattern and think about reusability and avoiding copying code

Comment: @SimonBarker Absolutely. And you can also consider having separate cells in that one tableViewController and just dequeing the one you want to use at the time.

Comment: huh, ok - so is that the point of the reuseidentifer? To allow you to choose different types of cell based on what's happening in the code?